# Get all remaining posts after a particular post id

Tags: wp-query

We all know and its easy to get posts using `WP_Query`. We can filter, orderby etc.
I am in a situation, where I would like to get all remaining posts after a post id, say `100`. So what I need is to get all posts, ordered, filtered but only the remaining of `100`.

Is there any tweak for this to achieve in `WP_Query`? If anybody gone through this before, advise me?

Comment: Is this for a main query or a secondary query?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
    [ 
        'wpse_pid'        => 100,    // Our custom post id argument
        'wpse_compare'    => '>',    // Out custom compare argument (<,>,<=,>=,!=,<>)
        'posts_per_page'  => 100,    // Modify this to your needs             
    ] 
);
```

where we use the following plugin to support these two custom arguments:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Support for post ID filtering in WP_Query
 * Description: Uses wpse_pid and wpse_compare arguments
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/193415/26350
*/
add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $where, $q )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if( $pid = $q->get( 'wpse_pid' ) )
    {
        // Get the compare input
        $cmp = $q->get( 'wpse_compare' );

        // Only valid compare strings allowed:
        $cmp = in_array( 
            $cmp, 
            [ '<', '>', '!=', '<>', '<=', '>=' ] 
        )
           ? $cmp
           : '=';  // default

        // SQL part
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID {$cmp} %d ", $pid ) ;
    }
    return $where;

}, 10, 2 );
```

*Note that this assumes PHP versions 5.4+.*